# mirror image algorithm not working properly

Tags: java, image, colors, swap

I am trying to write a program that mirrors an image. I have tried everything but can't get my code to work properly. What it should do is take the pixel from the left in a row and a pixel from the right in the same row and swap their colors. Below I have included my code and the code for the methods of the Pixel class that I used. Can someone please help?

NOTE: All methods in the Pixel class work as they were given to me

NOTE: In my code below `this` refers to the picture

My Code:

```
    public void mirror() {
      Pixel leftPixel;
      Pixel rightPixel;
      Color temp = new Color(255, 255, 255);

      for(int y = 0; y < this.getHeight(); y += 1) { //this.getHeight() is the height of the image in pixels
          for(int x = 0; x < this.getWidth(); x += 1) { //this.getWidth() is the width of the image in pixels
              leftPixel = new Pixel(this, x, y);
              rightPixel = new Pixel(this, (this.getWidth() - 1) - x, y);

              temp = leftPixel.getColor();
              leftPixel.setColor(rightPixel.getColor());
              rightPixel.setColor(temp);
          }
       }
    }
```

Pixel object description
A pixel has a column (x) and row (y) location in a picture. A pixel knows how to get and set the red, green, blue, and alpha values in the picture. A pixel also knows how to get and set the color using a Color object.

Pixel class methods used:

---

Get Color:

public Color getColor()

Method to get a color object that represents the color at this pixel.

Returns:
   a color object that represents the pixel color

---

Set Color

public void setColor(Color newColor)

Method to set the pixel color to the passed in color object.

Parameters:
newColor - the new color to use

---

[Original Picture/My Current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYekD.jpg)

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3mwO.jpg)